# Difficult to open bank accounts in EU countries?

Tags: banking

In USA, I cannot open a checking or savings account because I choose not to unlock my credit records.  (Credit check required to **deposit**, not borrow?!?)

In Spain, only an ID and address needed to open a savings account and get a debit card.  No raised eyebrows at a USA address.  No credit check—which would have been empty, since I have never borrowed outside of USA and not at all in at least a decade.

Is it generally this sensible throughout EU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is **not** that simple (among other things) due to money laundering legislation and in general to registration laws.

In Germany it is very difficult, as a non-resident, to open a bank account.

There are, however, certain **Direct banks** where this is possible. The [German Bank account for non residents](https://www.auswandern-handbuch.de/how-to-open-a-german-bank-account-for-non-residents/) article (which may not be impartial) gives a overview on what is on offer and many of the conditions for the banks listed.

So for a 'roamer' through Europe this may be of interest.

**Note**:
**US citizens** may encounter problems, due to [FATCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act), while attempting to open an account. Some banks are reluctant to accepts US citizens due to the high costs that the implementation of the FATCA rules bring with it.

---

**Sources**:

- [How to open a German Bank account for non residents - Auswandern Handbuch](https://www.auswandern-handbuch.de/how-to-open-a-german-bank-account-for-non-residents/)
- [Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act (FATCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act)